# Package upgrade failing ubuntu-advantage-tools and libfprint-2-2

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, updates, ubuntu-advantage

I am aware of [Error Upgrading ubuntu-advantage-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354320/error-upgrading-ubuntu-advantage-tools) and the corresponding bug. I checked and made sure that the latest patch provided by Richard Harding is present on my machine. I also installed cloud-id (which was not installed earlier) and still the same problem. which is:

```
sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing 
[sudo] password for mbajpai: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libgs9-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libfprint-2-2 ubuntu-advantage-tools
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,065 kB of archives.
After this operation, 94.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools amd64 27.4.2~20.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libfprint-2-2 amd64 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-advantage-tools/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.4.2~20.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libfprint/libfprint-2-2_1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
```

Before this, I ran:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update 
Hit:1 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                      
Get:3 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1,481 B]            
Get:4 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1,474 B]                              
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                   
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                 
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease         
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Fetched 2,955 B in 2s (1,375 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
10 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

I guess I can remove `libfprint-2-2` but `ubuntu-advantage-tools` seems more fundamental. Please advise.

Edit: additional info as asked:

**sudo apt -f install**

```
[sudo] password for ****: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 53 not upgraded.
```

**cat /etc/apt/sources.list**

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo apt -f install` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: I can't speak with authority here, but I've noted discussions on problems with Ubuntu Advantage tools (*changes are occurring; some issues are only in how new information is being presented; changing that has caused other issues*) but with 20.04 LTS you won't get benefit of it until after April-2025 so it's not critical/fundamental yet.  However a quick look at and I see `libfprint | 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.6             | focal-updates   | source` so I'd check sources are up-to-date as your paste shows an older package..

Comment: @Someone provided the info you asked for.

Comment: @guiverc how to i check for up to date sources?

Comment: I used a terminal command to look for packages (`rmadison`) as I'm using a different release; but you can search online too using https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libfprint which will show the same details (*just formatted slightly differently; and without ESM release details I get at terminal*).  To update your sources a simple `sudo apt update` will cause your system to update it's package information.. You trying days later & that command would have been executed by the system automatically a couple of times...

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same steps a reboot and two days later and it all just worked. I believe the reboot cleared some cache.

**sudo apt upgrade**

```
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools amd64 27.5~20.04.1 [861 kB]
...
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libfprint-2-2 amd64 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.6 [207 kB]
```